# Ajax post not appending data to URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to get my search bar working, however I am having issues with an ajax post.

For whatever reason, none of the data is being appended to the URL. I have tried various things with no success. I am attempting to send the data to the same page (index.php).

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on({
    click: function () {
      var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
      for (var i = tables.length-1; i >= 0; i-= 1) {
        if (tables[i]) tables[i].parentNode.removeChild(tables[i]);
      }

      var text = $('#searchBar').val();
      var postData = JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: text });

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postData,
        success: function() {
          alert("Test");
        }
      });
    }
  }, "#searchButton");
});
```

And here is the php which I have with index.php:

```
<?php
    require('course.php');

    if(isset($_POST['searchTerm'])) {
        echo $_POST['searchTerm'];
    }
?>
```

No matter what I try, I am unable to get anything to post. I have checked the network tab in chrome, and I'm not seeing anything that indicates it's working correctly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've changed my code to this, and it seems I'm getting closer:

```
$(document).on({
  click: function () {
    $("TABLE").remove()

    var text = $('#searchBar').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'index.php',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: { searchTerm: text },
      success: function() {
        alert("Test");
      }
    });
  }
}, "#searchButton");
```

And:

```
<?php
  require('course.php');

  if(isset($_GET['searchTerm'])) {
    echo $_GET['searchTerm'];
  }
?>
```

Now I am getting `?searchTerm=theTextIEnter` as expected, however it's still not being echoed in index.php.

Comment: Have you tried a GET instead of POST?

Comment: @bukko Yes. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Also why not `$("TABLE").remove()` instead of the loop?

Comment: See my answer below. Your original code worked, you just had to remove `dataType: 'json'` The `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting in the response (e.g. what index.php is sending back). It's not the type of data you're sending in the query. So you were setting dataType to 'json', but receiving non-JSON back in the response. That's why it wasn't *working*, or `echo`'ing back to the screen.

Comment: "it's still not being echoed in index.php." — It should be. Are you actually looking at the response to the Ajax request (still in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools)? Or are you expecting it to magically appear in the HTML document you are already looking at in the main browser window despite not having written any code to make that happen?

Comment: try the code given by me ... it will help you... @user3746428

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala Unfortunately I wasn't able to get that to work. I did notice that typing the parameter manually into the search bar does work, however the code I've got doesn't seem to add the parameters itself.

Comment: use `url: "index.php?searchTerm="+text` and remove data from ajax request with get method

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala — That will just stop it being properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `JSON.stringify()` to convert object to string. `data` passed to `$.ajax` must be an object and not JSON.

Comment: Changing that now calls the alert in the success function, but still doesn't append the data.

Comment: `data passed to $.ajax must be an object and not JSON.` this isn't true - you can pass JSON if you want to, but it's better to provide an object so that jQuery will escape the values for you.

Comment: @user3746428 where is the append code you are written? i didn't see anywhere

Comment: Debug in the browser. Add a break-point at the start of the script and step through.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if `data` is string, it's treated as a query string.

Comment: That's right. It's an odd case, but certainly possible and can work.

Answer (score 0):

> For whatever reason, none of the data is being appended to the URL.

You are making a POST request. POST data is sent in the request body, not in the query string component of the URL.

If you change it to a GET request (and inspect it in the correct place, i.e. the Network tab of your browser's developer tools and not the address bar for the browser) then you would see the data in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data via the URL you have to use a GET request. To do this, change the `type` of the request to `GET` and give the object directly to the `data` parameter in your jQuery, and use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` in your PHP.

Finally note that you're not returning JSON - you're returning text. If you want to return JSON, use `json_encode` and get the value in the parameter of the `success` handler function.

Try this:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        $('table').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { searchTerm: $('#searchBar').val() },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.searchTerm);
            }
        });
    }
}, "#searchButton");
```

```php
<?php
    require('course.php');

    if(isset($_GET['searchTerm'])) {
        echo json_encode(array('searchTerm' => $_GET['searchTerm']));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Still nothing... `if(isset($_GET['searchTerm']))` is returning false. Also, I only see `index.php?` top bar, but in the network tab of chrome I see `index.php?searchTerm=test`. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes that is normal, although I have no idea why this isn't working for you. What do you get from the request if you comment out the `if` and just have the `echo` with a hardcoded value?

Answer (score 0):

**With POST Request:**

Please comment below line in your code:

```
//var postData = JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: text });
```

And use below ajax code to get the post-data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { searchTerm: text },
    success: function() {
      alert("Test");
    }
  });
```

**With GET Request:**

You can convert your data to query string parameters and pass them along to the server that way.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php?searchTerm='+text,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
```

In response, You can get the data with alert, so you may get idea about the same.

Comment: @user3746428, Please check my updated answer, and also please accept my answer if it's make sense to resolve your problem. Let me know if you still found any issues, I'll happy to help you around.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you use `data: { postData }` on place of `data:postData` and you will receive your data in `$_POST['postData']`

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on({
    click: function () {
      var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
      for (var i = tables.length-1; i >= 0; i-= 1) {
        if (tables[i]) tables[i].parentNode.removeChild(tables[i]);
      }

      var text = $('#searchBar').val();
      var postData = JSON.stringify({ 'searchTerm' : text });

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
         data: { postData },
         success: function(data) {
          alert(data.searchTerm);
        }
      });
    }
  }, "#searchButton");
});
```

In index.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['postData'])) {
        echo $_POST['postData'];
        die;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dataType: 'json',` from your `AJAX`. That is all.

Your response type is not `JSON`, yet by setting `dataType: 'json'` you're implying that it is. So when no JSON is detected in the response, nothing gets sent back to the method handler. By removing `dataType` it allows the API to make an educated decision on what the response type is going to be, based on the data you're returning in the response. Otherwise, you can set `dataType` to 'text' or 'html' and it will work.

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **dataType**: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

This is NOT the type of data you're *sending*/*posting*, it's what you're expecting back. And in your `index.php` file you're not sending back any `JSON`. This is why the `success()` method is not satisfying. Always set the `dataType` to the type of data you're *expecting* back in the response.